# Symfony2 using getArrayResult not returning correct result

Tags: arrays, symfony, one-to-many, query-builder

My code is :

```
return $this->repository->createQueryBuilder("z")
        ->select("absence","eleve","note")
        ->from("AppBundle:Absence", "absence")
        ->join("absence.eleve","eleve")
        ->join("eleve.notes","note")
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
```

absence.eleve is a ManyToOne relationship and eleve.notes is a OneToMany RelationShip, so after many experiences i noticed that when i move from the ManyToOne to the OneToMany eleve.notes is an array that contains always a single object, can you please help me to figure it out.

This is an example of the result :

```
{"absences":
    [
        {"id":1,"column1":"***","eleve":
            {"id":38,"notes":
                [
                    {"id":131,"note":10}
                ]
            }
        },
        {"id":2,"column1":"***","eleve":
            {"id":39,"notes":
                [
                    {"id":130,"note":5}
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

when in do this :

```
return $this->repository->createQueryBuilder("z")
            ->select("eleve","note")
            ->from("AppBundle:Eleve", "eleve")
            ->join("eleve.notes","note")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
```

it works fine and for each eleve notes is an array of multiple objects.

Comment: Is repository the Alieve repository or the Eleve repository?  I don't think it actually matters but wanted to make sure.

Comment: it's the absence Entity Repository
even if i use 
return $this->repository->createQueryBuilder("absence")
            ->select("absence","eleve","note")
            ->join("absence.eleve", "eleve")
            ->join("eleve.notes","note")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
i has the same result

Comment: You could try leftJoin instead of join but I don't think that will help.  Maybe look at the generated sql query.  But what you posted looks like it should work.

Comment: yes my friend i tried the leftJoin but it doesn't help

Comment: have try add `with`, check this: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods ??

Comment: how do you suggest to use it ?

Comment: downgrading doctrine orm to version 2.4.7 solved the problem